# geographic location of VPS

Tags: vps

I purchased a VPS, but I have my suspicions the server is not in the location I requested (Amsterdam). Is there a reliable way to determine the physical location of a VPS (using it's IP address, presumably).

Comment: IP address is not a reliable way of determining the physical location of a computer anyway, so its certainly not going to help you here (while it can work good enough for a few things, it presumes trust, and you clearly don't trust the provider so you can't trust their data)...

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you don't think it's in Amsterdam? Why would you stay with a host who lies about something this basic, anyways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grab a test IP from a datacenter in Amsterdam and ping it from your VPS. The ping is typically 1-3 milliseconds in the same city, though this can vary, assuming there is no quick route between the two locations.

You can use this looking glass: http://www.leasewebnoc.com/lg.html It has three locations in Amsterdam you can ping/trace from.

Comment: +1. Anything 10ms or higher is highly suspicious. 1ms is LOW but it should be below 10ms stable without any problems.

Comment: Overloaded server may give you surprise...

Answer (score 4):

MaxMind GeoCity usually give more or less accurate results. Even hosts in same DC from different nets may have exotic route, thus - **ping isn't reliable way at all**

Answer (score 0):

The GeoIP tool provides more accurate location. Use the IP address allocated to you. I am able to get exact locations as my provider specified.

http://www.geoiptool.com/